# Issue with now function in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying out date range aggregation in elasticsearch 2.3. I want to aggregate them as last 30 days, last 7 days and today. Hence part of my aggregation query as follows:

```
"range": {
   "ranges": [
      {
        "from": "now-30d/d",
        "to": "now/d"
      },
      {
        "from": "now-7d/d",
        "to": "now/d"
      },
      {
        "from": "now/d",
        "to": "now+1d/d"
      }
    ],
    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
  }
```

This is resulting in below buckets:

```
"buckets": [
    {
      "key": "2017-01-23-2017-02-22",
      "from": 1485129600000,
      "from_as_string": "2017-01-23",
      "to": 1487721600000,
      "to_as_string": "2017-02-22",
      "doc_count": 6
    },
    {
      "key": "2017-02-15-2017-02-22",
      "from": 1487116800000,
      "from_as_string": "2017-02-15",
      "to": 1487721600000,
      "to_as_string": "2017-02-22",
      "doc_count": 6
    },
    {
      "key": "2017-02-22-2017-02-23",
      "from": 1487721600000,
      "from_as_string": "2017-02-22",
      "to": 1487808000000,
      "to_as_string": "2017-02-23",
      "doc_count": 0
    }
  ]
```

The output of `date` command in the machine where elasticsearch is installed is as follows:

```
Tue Feb 21 23:01:59 PST 2017
```

As seen from the buckets, elasticsearch function `now` is evaluated to `2017-02-22`, but I expected it to be `2017-02-21`. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: now is not affected by the time_zone parameter (dates must be stored as UTC). try changing your timezone to UTC

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/several-date-math-questions/27453/4

Answer (score 0):

After going through the documentation again, I understood that `now` function uses UTC time not the timezone of the machine where elasticsearch is installed. Hence this behavior was seen. This has been fixed in latest version of elasticsearch where `time_zone` attribute can be specified in date range aggregation. This issue is tracked here-
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10130